# Manage Desktop program seting and features in the cloud

Tags: windows, delphi, cloud, settings

A program I have written has many modules we can turn on or off depending on the clients preference or if the client pays for the feature. Some features may be charged on a subscription basses and needs to expire after a given date

I am looking for a cloud based solution I could have like a dashboard and be able to see all the clients and what features are set and be able to control (Turn on Turn Off and set expiration dates) these features of my program in a central place.

Is there any such service out there or something I could easily tweak to do this?

What would be building blocks if I need to design on by myself for cheap? 
It would be used by around 100-300 clients

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look for **delphi BAAS cloud**
Unfortunately I didn't try to show you some example, but have some videos on Youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqeFAuURBro

Comment: I am wondering if there is somewhat a turnkey solution to this